# search_file_replace method regular expression issue (Ruby)

Tags: ruby

There is a line in a file:

> "recipe[sometext::anothertext]",

and it has 4 spaces in the beginning.

I need to replace it with:

> "recipe[sometext::anothertext_v2]",

and leave those spaces be.

I was trying different approaches and nothing helped. Here is one of them:

```
fe = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new("#{home_dir}/environment/#{environment}/" + node.run_state["hostname"] + "/node.json")
fe.search_file_replace(/\"recipe\[sometext::anothertext/, '"recipe[sometext::anothertext_v2')
fe.write_file
```

Is there something wrong with the file path? How to fix the regexp in search_file_replace? Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the output?Have you tried your regex in something like https://regex101.com/ ?

Comment: And have you checked, wheter there is any file being written?

Comment: @RolandStuder yes, I checked the regex in rubular.com. It appeared that the issue is in another place, everything is fine with my code example.

Comment: have you checked `unwritten_changes?` on `fe` if this is `false` then there is a problem with your regex because the functionality of `search_file_replace` is actually very simple and basically the way I would have written it without Chef. (e.g. `map!`, `match` and `gsub!`)

Comment: @АнтонКацапов So what doesn't work? Which part of the code fails?